# AnsibleUnderfinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_fqdn'

Tags: ansible

I want to get the fqdns of remote hosts, and I planned to get it by:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
Hello {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['ansible_fqdn'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

but then I got an error saying "AnsibleUnderfinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_fqdn'", but I can get the information of a fqdn by this command:

```
$ ansible all -m setup -a "filter=*fqdn*"
172.25.250.9 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_fqdn: "workstation.lab.example.com",
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

So my confusion is Why I can get the variable by setup in a command line, but can't do by a playbook?
Can you rescue me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
Hello {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_fqdn'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This requires that you've gathered facts on all the hosts in your inventory; otherwise, facts like `ansible_fqdn` won't be available. You may want to handle missing values more gracefully:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
Hello {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_fqdn']|default("(missing)") }}
{% endfor %}
```

For example:

```
# This play is necessary to gather facts on all the hosts
# in our inventory.
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

# Now we can use host facts in our templates.
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for host in groups['all'] %}
          Hello {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_fqdn']|default("(missing)") }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice! The problem now can be solved and you rescued me. You are the best one!  Thank you ,hahahaha

Comment: @ Zeitounator, I have not found the icon before you telled  me. Yes, I should mark the answer that larsks spent a lot of time on as the accepted answer.